How should I use @HostListener inside a method in this Angular 16 app?
I have been working on an SPA with Angular 16, TypeScript and The Movie Database (TMDB).
I need to do an "infinite scroll" feature on one of the component.
For this purpose, I have:
export class MoviesByGenre {

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private movieService: MovieService
  ) { }

  public genreName: string | undefined = '';

  public movieResponse!: MovieResponse;
  public movies: Movie[] | undefined = [];

  public genreResponse!: GenreResponse;
  public genres: Genre[] | undefined = [];

  public getMoviesByGenre(): void {

    // Get genre id (from URL parameter)
    const genreId = Number(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));

    const maxPage: number = 10;
    let pageNumber: number = 1;
    let isLoading: boolean = false;

    // Get genre name from genres array
    this.movieService.getAllMovieGenres().subscribe((response) => {
      this.genreResponse = response;
      this.genres = this.genreResponse.genres;

      if (this.genres && this.genres.length) {
        let currentGenre = this.genres.find(genre => genre.id === genreId);
        if (currentGenre) {
          this.genreName = currentGenre.name || '';
          this.movieService.defaultTitle = this.genreName;
        }
      }
    });

    // Get movies by genre id
    this.movieService.getMoviesByGenre(genreId, pageNumber).subscribe((response) => {
      this.movieResponse = response;
      this.movies = this.movieResponse.results;

      @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
       onWindowScroll(event) {
        if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight &&! isLoading) {
          if (pageNumber < maxPage) {
            isLoading = true;
        
            // Push into the movies array
            this.movies?.push(...this.movies);
        
            // Increment page number
            pageNumber++;
        
            isLoading = false;
          }
        }
      }
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(() => {
      this.getMoviesByGenre();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.movieService.defaultTitle = '';
  }

}

The problem
I was not expecting @HostListener to fail inside my getMoviesByGenre() method, but it does.
It throws this error:
TS1146: Declaration expected.
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])

I have added a stackblitz here.
Questions

What am I doing wrong?
Is there a viable alternative to using @HostListener?


I'm pretty sure you cannot use @HostListener inside the scope of a method. I've only ever seen it in the class scope. So you could fix this by promoting onWindowScroll to a class method and handling the case where the movies haven't loaded yet inside the event handler.

Is there a viable alternative to using @HostListener?

You could manually add an event listener to the host element, but that would just be doing the same work as @HostListener. Is there a reason onWindowScroll can't be a class method?

@DM There is no other reason for wich onWindowScroll not to be a class method then keeping the logic related to the movies array in the getMoviesByGenre() method. So I prefer it like that.

you'll keep adding eventlisteners when you get results if you do this.  The error is coming because you are calling that from inside an anonymous function.   Don't think you can use imports in there?  Maybe declare it globally... but again, you don't want to keep adding eventlisteners.

why not use cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport?, like e.g this SO related to an infinite scroll with FormArray

@Eliseo Doing this, made the list of movies nor render at all: <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="auto"><div *cdkVirtualFor="let movie of movies" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3"><app-movie-card class="movie card" [movie]="movie" [showGenres]="false"></app-movie-card></div></cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>.

Thank you, the stackblitz started working, please find below the implementation code.
How to make infinite scroll in JS <- article helped me
We can just call the API call on load, with page number 1. Then on each subsequent scroll, we increment the page number and then make the API call again, but we push the new results into the array, instead of assigning it, this creates the infinite scroll effect!
ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(window, 'scroll')
      .pipe(
        startWith(0),
        map((x) => window?.scrollY),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      )
      .subscribe((scrollPos: any) => {
        if (!this.movies?.length) {
          return;
        }
        console.log(scrollPos + window.innerHeight); //scrolled from top
        console.log(document.documentElement.scrollHeight); //visible part of screen
        if (
          Math.round(scrollPos + window.innerHeight) >=
            document.documentElement.scrollHeight &&
          this.pageNumber < this.maxPage
        ) {
          this.pageNumber++;
          this.getMoviesByPage(this.genreId, this.pageNumber);
        }
      });
  }

FULL CODE:
TS:
import { Component, EventEmitter, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { GenreResponse, Genre } from '../../models/Genre';
import { MovieResponse, Movie } from '../../models/Movie';
import { MovieService } from '../../services/movie-service.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { distinctUntilChanged, fromEvent, map, startWith } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movies-by-genre',
  templateUrl: './movies-by-genre.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movies-by-genre.component.scss'],
})
export class MoviesByGenre {
  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private movieService: MovieService
  ) {}

  public genreName: string | undefined = '';

  public movieResponse!: MovieResponse;
  public movies: Movie[] = [];
  public moviesBuffer: Movie[] | undefined = [];

  public genreResponse!: GenreResponse;
  public genres: Genre[] | undefined = [];
  scrollCount = 10;
  genreId!: number;
  maxPage: number = 10;
  pageNumber: number = 1;
  isLoading: boolean = false;
  public getMoviesByGenre(): void {
    // Get genre id (from URL parameter)
    this.genreId = Number(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));

    // Get genre name from genres array
    this.movieService.getAllMovieGenres().subscribe((response) => {
      this.genreResponse = response;
      this.genres = this.genreResponse.genres;

      if (this.genres && this.genres.length) {
        let currentGenre = this.genres.find(
          (genre) => genre.id === this.genreId
        );
        if (currentGenre) {
          this.genreName = currentGenre.name || '';
          this.movieService.defaultTitle = this.genreName;
        }
      }
    });
    this.getMoviesByPage(this.genreId, this.pageNumber);
  }

  getMoviesByPage(genreId: number, pageNumber: number) {
    // Get movies by genre id
    this.movieService
      .getMoviesByGenre(genreId, pageNumber)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.movieResponse = response;
        this.movies.push(...(this.movieResponse?.results || []));
      });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(window, 'scroll')
      .pipe(
        startWith(0),
        map((x) => window?.scrollY),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      )
      .subscribe((scrollPos: any) => {
        if (!this.movies?.length) {
          return;
        }
        console.log(scrollPos + window.innerHeight); //scrolled from top
        console.log(document.documentElement.scrollHeight); //visible part of screen
        if (
          Math.round(scrollPos + window.innerHeight) >=
            document.documentElement.scrollHeight &&
          this.pageNumber < this.maxPage
        ) {
          this.pageNumber++;
          this.getMoviesByPage(this.genreId, this.pageNumber);
        }
      });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(() => {
      this.getMoviesByGenre();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.movieService.defaultTitle = '';
  }
}

HTML
<ng-container *ngIf="movieResponse">
  <div class="row grid">
    <div
      *ngFor="let movie of movies"
      class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3"
    >
      <app-movie-card class="movie card" [movie]="movie"></app-movie-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>

Stackblitz Demo

We need to take a ViewChild of the the scrollable div.
@ViewChild('scroller') scroller!: ElementRef<any>;

Then in ngAfterViewInit, we can use rxjs fromEvent to listen for scroll and apply the logic you need
ngAfterViewInit() {
    if(scroller?.nativeElement) {
        // for window or anything else
        // fromEvent(window, 'scroll')
        // for some div
        fromEvent(scroller.nativeElement, 'scroll').pipe(
            startWith(0), 
            map(x => window?.scrollY), 
            distinctUntilChanged(),
        ).subscribe((scrollPos: any) => {
            // apply logic here!
        });
    }
}


I want all the logic related to getting and adding to the movies array in the getMoviesByGenre() method.

I have added a stackblitz here.

They do work. The code does not compile.

Great, buy I have not seen any use of the maxPage variable in the script. I want a maximum of 10 pages of movies loaded.

For some reason, the app never loads more then 3 pages of movies (filtered by genre), even though there are more to load (I have checked on themoviedb.org.)

Have you also updated the stackblitz?

For some reason, after I visit a genre page (like by-genre/16, for instance), the app keeps making http requests regardless of the route I am on.

@RazvanZamfir The API calls are coming from MovieCardComponent getAllMovieGenres method, could you try returning the genre also when you fetch the list of movies, this will resolve your issue, it better to be done from the backend basically!

I don't see how I could do that. :(

@RazvanZamfir it's doable, but the solution works from frontend perspective
